# when we type a text in input box than loader is start loading. but we want loader only work when we press enter key

Tags: javascript, php, css, angularjs

when we type a text in the input box then the loader starts loading. but we want loader only to work when we press enter key

// Function is called when user enter input any text in filter box
$scope.gridGuestsApi.core.on.filterChanged($scope, function () {
$scope.direct = false;
$scope.oppvmware_guestlist_loading = true;  // To show the loader
});

this is html code

Answer (score 1):

Possible to achive with `keyup.enter` to trigger function `loader()`. Can also be used with `keydown` event listener. By relying upon Angular’s keydown.enter pseudo-event, it is no longer necessary to manually check to see if the event.key value is Enter - though you could pass in the `$event` and check if it is `Enter` e.g `loader($event)`.

```html
 <input type="text" (keyup.enter)="loader()" />
```